Derivation of Green's representation formula via distributions
Consider the following boundary problem of the Poisson equation for the unkown function $u$:
$$\Delta u=f \ \text{on } U,\phantom{aaa} u=g \ \text{on } \partial U,$$
where $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is open, bounded and with smooth boundary. A Green function for $U$ can then be defined as a real valued function $G:U\times \overline U \to \mathbb{R}$, $ \ (x,y)\mapsto G(x,y)$ which solves the problem
$$\Delta_y G(x,\cdot )=\delta_x,\phantom{aaaaa} G(x,y)=0 \ \text{for all } y\in\partial U$$
for each fixed value $x\in U$. Here, $\delta_x$ is the Dirac-delta and the equation is to be understood in the distributional sense.
There is an easy formal derivation for Green's reprsentation formula for solutions of the Poisson boundary problem using the Dirac-delta and the above definition of Green's functions: If $u(x)$ is a solution to the above Poisson problem with $u\in C^2(U)\cap C(\overline U)$, then, using partial integration twice, we get
\begin{align*}
u(x) &= \int_U u(y)\delta_x dy=\int_U u(y)\Delta_y G(x,y)dy \\[5pt]
&= \int_{\partial U} u(y) \bigl(N(y)\cdot\nabla_y G(y,x)\bigr)\:dS(y) - \int_U \nabla u(y) \cdot \nabla_y G(x,y)dy\\[5pt]
&= \int_{\partial U} u(y) \bigl(N(y)\cdot\nabla_y G(y,x)\bigr)\:dS(y)\\[5pt] 
 &\phantom{aaaaa} - \; \int_{\partial U} \bigl(N(y)\cdot \nabla u(y)\bigr)G(x,y)\: dS(y) 
 \; + \; \int_U \Delta u(y) G(x,y)\:dy \\[5pt]
&= \int_{\partial U} g(y) \bigl( N(y)\cdot G(x,y)\bigr)\: dS(y) 
  + \int_U f(y)G(x,y) \: dy.
\end{align*}
In this calculation, $N$ is the outward normal unit field of $\partial U$.
My question: Can this "formal" calculation made into a rigorous proof of Green's representation formula?
One problem I encountered here is that $u$ is not a test function and so it is not clear to me where to start.
A reference to the literature where such a derivation of Green's theorem is explained in some detail might also be helpful.

Yes, this can indeed be made into a rigorous proof. It follows along this line of thought:
First, derive a representation formula for any function $u \in C^2(U) \cap C^1(\overline U)$ by using the fundamental solution $\Gamma$ of the Laplace equation. This leads to
$$u(x)= \int_U \Gamma(x-y)\Delta u(y) dy + \int_{\partial U} \left[\Gamma(x-y) \partial_{n}u(y) - \partial_n\Gamma(x-y) u(y) \right ] dS(y)$$
where $\partial_n$ denotes the normal derivative. This formula can be derived as follows: For fixed $x \in U$, cut out a small ball $B_\epsilon(x)$ around $x$ and look at $U_\epsilon:= U \backslash B_\epsilon(x)$. There, the fundamental solution is $C^2$ and we may use Green's integration by parts formula (derived from the Gauss theorem) to obtain the equality
$$\int_{U_\epsilon}( u(y) \Delta_y \Gamma(y-x) - \Gamma(y-x) \Delta u(y)) dy = \int_{\partial U_\epsilon}\dots$$
We separate $\partial U_\epsilon$ into $\partial U$ and $\partial B_\epsilon(x)$.
Then we show that some terms converge to zero as $\epsilon \to 0$ and we can explicitely compute some other terms and after letting $\epsilon \to 0$ we will end up with the formula claimed above.
Second: The problem with this formula is that it includes the normal derivative of $u$ which is not known for a solution to the Poisson problem. Therefore we introduce Green's function as a "correction term" and using again Green's integration by parts formula we end upt with
$$u(x) = \int_U G(x,y) \Delta u(y) dy - \int_{\partial U} \partial_n G(x,y) u(y) dS(y).$$
Third: we plug in the data from the equation in the last formula and end up with Green's representation formula. Note that in your calculation in the question there is a mistake. The boundary integral when it appears first is not the same as in the last line. The term $N(y) \nabla_yG(y,x)$ is the same as $\partial_nG$ in my formula and you somehow got rid of the gradient in your last equality - which should not have happened. Therefore in the last line, there is still a normal derivative of the Green function $G$.
As to literature: The book "Partial Differential Equations" by L.C. Evans explains the heuristics of this in chapter 2.2.4; however it does not include the rigorous proof for my "first" step.
